# Saving the model of an encoder decoder

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

I'm having trouble working out how to save the full model on the below link.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/image_captioning

I want to use the below code but I cant workout what "model" is in the below. I tried saving the checkpoints but thats not really what I want to do. I realise this is probably a really easy question but for some reason I cant do it.

```
# Save the entire model as a SavedModel.
!mkdir -p saved_model
model.save('saved_model/my_model')
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your intent: You want to save the model for TensorFlow Serving, right?

Comment: Yes exactly. Thanks